# Can someone break down this code for non-overlapping occurrences in Python?

Tags: python, string, count, substring

Suppose count doesn't exist.

```
string = 'let it be let it'
substring = 'let it'
count = 0
sub_len = len(substring) 
for i in range(len(string)): 
    if string[i:i+sub_len] == substring:
        count += 1
print(count)
>>> 2
```

What's confusing me exactly is this part

```
for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i:i+sub_len] == substring:
        count += 1
```

And more specifically

```
    if string[i:i+sub_len] == substring:
```

I don't get how this adds to the count?

Could someone explain this to me, especially the part in the brackets.

Comment: Do you understand Python slice notation?

Answer (score 0):

Python has a feature called [**slicing**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html) which allow you to extract a substring from a string by specifying the start and end indicies (where the start is included and the end is excluded).

The syntax for this is:

```
some_string[start:stop:step]
```

where all are optional.

So some examples from the documentation (linked above):

```
>>> word = 'Python'
>>> word[0:2]  # characters from position 0 (included) to 2 (excluded)
'Py'
>>> word[2:5]  # characters from position 2 (included) to 5 (excluded)
'tho'
>>> word[:2]   # character from the beginning to position 2 (excluded)
'Py'
>>> word[4:]   # characters from position 4 (included) to the end
'on'
>>> word[-2:]  # characters from the second-last (included) to the end
'on'
```

and to give one with the `step` included:

```
>>> word[::2]
'Pto'
```

---

So, to explain your code, a for-loop is used to iterate over the start indexes of the slice. Of course, these indexes range from `0` (the default to the `range()` function) to the length of the whole string.

In your case, since the length of `string` is `16`, the variable `i` will take the values: `0`, `1`, `2` ... `14`, `15`.

Then, you take the slice from the string that starts at the index `i` and ends at the index `i` + `sub_len`. Since `sub_len` is the length of the substring, this will take slices from `string` that are the same size (length) as the substring.

For example, the first ones are:

```
'let it'
'et it '
't it b'
...
'let it'
```

Now, the equivalence comparator (`==`) is used to check whether this substring is equal to the desired substring - if it is, the count variable is incremented.